# TableView doesn't refresh

Tags: java, javafx

I've got a project written in JavaFX and I'm trying to get a refresh on a tableview without result.
I've googled around and tried some examples I've found but it still doesn't work.

I populate a tableview with information each row in this table can have new comments added to by double click on the row. The a new Tabpane is opened and the new comment can be added there. On close of this tabpane I'd like the one I clicked from to be refreshed.
I must be doing something wrong. I just don't know what.

In my StoreController

```
private void populateTableView(List<Store> stores) {
    ObservableList<Store> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(stores);
    storeNumberColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Store, String>("id"));
    storePhoneColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Store, String>("phoneNbr"));
    chainColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Store, String>("chainId"));
    commentColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Store, ImageView>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Store, ImageView> p) {
            Integer numberOfComments = p.getValue().getCommentsCount();
            ReadOnlyObjectWrapper wrapper = null;
            if (numberOfComments == 0) {
                wrapper = null;
            } else if (numberOfComments == 1) {
                wrapper = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(new ImageView(COMMENT_SINGLE_FLAG_SOURCE));
            } else {
                wrapper = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(new ImageView(COMMENT_DOUBLE_FLAG_SOURCE));
            }
            return wrapper;
        }
    });
    storeTable.setItems(data);
    sortTable(storeTable, missedColumn);
}

@FXML
public void handleTableAction(MouseEvent event) {
    if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
        showNewCommentStage();
    }
}

private void showNewCommentStage() {
    initCommentController();
    Store store
            = storeTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().getValue();
    commentController.showNewStage(commentPane, store);
}
```

It seems like the call-function doesn't get called when the commentpane is closed.

CommentController

```
public void showNewStage(Pane pane, Store store) {
    this.store = store;
    initStage(pane);
    windowHandler = new WindowHandler(stage);
    effectHandler.playEffect(pane);
    constructCommentHeaders();
    List<Comment> comments;
    comments = commentService.listByStoreId(store.getId());
    populateCommentTable(comments);
}
```

Like I said I've tried a lot of the solutions found here on Stackoverflow but with no results. The Tableview doesn't refresh. The Stores and the Comments are in different database tables if that's important
Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

****EDIT****
The Store.class

```
public class Store extends CommentEntity {
    private String id;
    private String chainId;
    private String phoneNbr;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getChainId() {
        return chainId;
    }

    public void setChainId(String chainId) {
        this.chainId = chainId;
    }

    public String getPhoneNbr() {
        return phoneNbr;
    }

    public void setPhoneNbr(String phoneNbr) {
        this.phoneNbr = phoneNbr;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Store{" + "id=" + id + ", chainId=" + chainId + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public String getCommentIdentifier() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

The CommentEntity.Class

```
public abstract class CommentEntity {
    private int commentsCount;

    public int getCommentsCount() {
        return commentsCount;
    }

    public void setCommentsCount(int commentsCount) {
        this.commentsCount = commentsCount;
    }

    public abstract String getCommentIdentifier();
}
```

Thank you for input, I hadn't even reflected over the ImageView / String.

Comment: When and how are you editing the comment_table_column value? How the tableview knows that the new comment has been added to the one of items it renders?

Comment: What is the type of `commentColumn`? The types of the parameters in the call to `setCellValueFactory` don't really match: the signature for `TableColumn<S,T>` is `setCellValueFactory(Callback<CellDataFeatures<S,T>, ObservableValue<T>> factory)`. But you have a `Callback<CellDataFeatures<Store, ImageView>, ObservableValue<String>>`, which doesn't make sense. Is `T` `ImageView` or `String` for this column? It would probably also help if you showed your `Store` class.

Comment: I have added the Store class above.
I also tested to change the String to ImageView after @James_D reflection over the inconsistency of having both ImageView and String. It seems to make no difference, the image is showing.

The comments are added by double-clicking on a row in the tableview. A new Pane is opened and there the comment is added to database. I make a new query to the db when I close the comment pane and right now I make a call to populateTableView. Everything is ok, but it seems like the call-function is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

First, you need to distinguish between the *data* the cells in your column are displaying, and the *cells* that actually display those data. The `cellValueFactory` determines the *data* that are displayed. The `PropertyValueFactory` is a `cellValueFactory` implementation that references a JavaFX Property, so when you call

```
storeNumberColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Store, String>("id"));
```

it effectively tells the cells in the `storeNumberColumn` to call the `idProperty()` method on the `Store` object in the current row to get the data for the cell. (If no such method exists, it will try to use `getId()` as a backup plan.)

By default, you get a `cellFactory` that displays text resulting from calling `toString()` on the data generated by the `cellValueFactory`. In the case where your data are simply `String`s, this is usually what you need. In other cases, you often need to provide a `cellFactory` of your own to get the correct way to display the data.

In your case, the data for the `commentColumn` are simply the number of comments. You are going to display that by choosing an image based on that numeric value.

So you should have

```
TableColumn<Store, Number> commentColumn = new TableColumn<>("Comments");
```

For the `cellValueFactory`, you can just use

```
commentColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("commentsCount"));
```

Then you need a `cellFactory` that displays the appropriate `ImageView`:

```
commentColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Store, Number>, new TableCell<Store, Number>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell<Store, Number>() {
        private ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Number numberOfComments, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(count, empty) ;
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (numberOfComments.intValue() == 0) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else if (numberOfComments.intValue() == 1) {
                    imageView.setImage(new Image(COMMENT_SINGLE_FLAG_SOURCE));
                    setGraphic(imageView);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImage(new Image(COMMENT_DOUBLE_FLAG_SOURCE));
                    setGraphic(imageView);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The second issue is actually about the update. A `TableView` keeps its contents "live" by observing [JavaFX properties](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) that are provided by the `cellValueFactory` as `ObservableValue`s. If the value might change while the table is displayed, you **must** provide an actual property that can be observed: using a `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper` is no good (because it's read only, so it's wrapped value will not change). The `PropertyValueFactory` will also return a `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper` if you do not have JavaFX property accessor methods (i.e. if it is only using `getXXX()` methods to access the data). So your model class must provide JavaFX Properties.

You can make an immediate fix to this by updating `CommentEntity` to use an `IntegerProperty`:

```
public abstract class CommentEntity {
    private final IntegerProperty commentsCount = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public final int getCommentsCount() {
        return commentsCountProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setCommentsCount(int commentsCount) {
        commentsCountProperty().set(commentsCount);
    }

    public IntegerProperty commensCountProperty() {
        return commentsCount ;
    }

    public abstract String getCommentIdentifier();
}
```

I would also strongly recommend updating the `Store` class to use JavaFX Properties in a similar manner.